# Repetición de imágenes en Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel-5

estoy almacenando 3 imágenes en laravel pero al momento de guardarlos se duplican
Cuando los visualizo están de manera repetidos.

Este es mi controlador

```
     public function store(Request $request){



        $escuela = new Escuela();

        $escuela->student_id   = $request->studentId;
        $escuela->telephone      = $request->telephone;
        $escuela->contact        = $request->contact;


        if($request->hasFile('imageInfo1')){
            $imageInfo1 = $request->file('imageInfo1');
            $arrImageInfo1 = $this->createFile($imageInfo1);

            $escuela->original_name_image1 = $arrImageInfo1['nameOriginal'];
            $escuela->random_name_image1   = $arrImageInfo1['name'];
        }

        if($request->hasFile('imageInfo2')){
            $imageInfo2 = $request->file('imageInfo2');
            $arrImageInfo2 = $this->createFile($imageInfo2);

            $escuela->original_name_image2 = $arrImageInfo2['nameOriginal'];
            $escuela->random_name_image2   = $arrImageInfo2['name'];
        }

        if($request->hasFile('imageInfo3')){
            $imageInfo3 = $request->file('imageInfo3');
            $arrImageInfo3 = $this->createFile($imageInfo3);

            $escuela->original_name_image3 = $arrImageInfo3['nameOriginal'];
            $escuela->random_name_image3   = $arrImageInfo3['name'];
        }

        $failure->save();

        return redirect()->route('escuela.detail',['idescuela' => $escuela->id]);
    }

 public function createFile($file, $filePrefix = 'photo', $index = 0){
        $arrFile = array();
        $file = ($file) ? $file : null;

        if ($file === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $fileNameOriginal = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileExtension    = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName         = $filePrefix.'-' . (time()+$index) . '.' . $fileExtension;

        if($filePrefix === 'photo-gallery'){
            $filePath     = $file->storeAs('public/picture', $fileName);
        }else{
            $filePath     = $file->storeAs('public/picture', $fileName);
        }

        $arrFile['nameOriginal'] = $fileNameOriginal;
        $arrFile['extension']    = $fileExtension;
        $arrFile['name']         = $fileName;
        $arrFile['path']         = $filePath;
        return $arrFile;
    }
```

Esta es la vista para seleccionar las imágenes y guardarlas

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <label for="password">Insertar Imágenes:</label>
                            <div class="rows">
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="image1">Imagen 1:</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="image1" id="image1" name="imageInfo1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="image2">Imagen 2:</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="image2" id="image2" name="imageInfo2">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="image3">Imagen 3:</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="image3" id="image3" name="imageInfo3">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Al revisar en la Base de datos me sale lo siguiente

|imagen1|random_name1|imagen2|random_name2|imagen3|random_name3|

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es mostrar las 3 diferentes imágenes que yo eh subido y que no se repita nada mas una